# Check Large List of Emails for Spam Emails

Tags: php, wordpress, email, spam, email-spam

I accumulated a lot of emails from my Wordpress-based website, but I don't know if some of them are legit (in fact, I am sure many of them are not). I have a lot of knowledge when it comes to querying the database and getting the information I want to with Wordpress, however, how do I check each individual email for legitamacy.. I have PHP knowledge as well, so if there's a solution there, that would be cool.

A couple of things to keep in mind though.

- I'm not wanting a solution for email validation, because they are all valid technically.
- I AM interested in using a database or pinging each or whatever, something to figure out if a particular email address isn't spam or something.

Comment: So, what, you want a service that'll tell you if an email is from a spammer or not? Have you tried spamhaus.org or doing a Google search for such services?

Comment: I looked around for a bit on Google, but I didn't find what I was looking for. I've heard of spamhaus.org but I will check them out, and see what I can do with the emails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In their article, [Why can't I use MailChimp to clean my list?](http://kb.mailchimp.com/article/why-cant-i-use-mailchimp-to-clean-my-list), MailChimp (a leading ESP) recommends these third party services for validating and cleaning your list:

- http://www.briteverify.com/brite-pricing
- http://www.datavalidation.com/email-validation-pricing/
- http://www.leadspend.com/mailchimp-promo

Some Email-marketing Service Providers (ESPs) offer features to filter out known-bad-addresses, but ultimately the responsibility falls on the list manager. **The most reliable way to validate an email address is by a two-step question and response**: first, an email address is entered during sign-up; second, an email is sent to the submitted address requesting confirmation; third, the recipient clicks a link confirming their subscription. This ensures that the email address is technically capable of receiving emails and that the intended recipient has access to that email account. In traditional email marketing, this process takes place during the initial account creation or subscription process and is commonly referred to as "[double opt-in](http://kb.mailchimp.com/article/how-does-confirmed-optin-or-double-optin-work/)".

Comment: Is the list of service providers that offer cleaning not helpful? I realize it's not a manual process that you're coding yourself in PHP, but it would produce the desired results: segregation of non-"SPAM" addresses from valid ones.

Comment: I made changes to my answer objectively for the sake of anyone else visiting this page while asking a similar question. You should do the same with your votes.

Answer (score 0):

Just an hint: if you look for an antispam filter for WordPress, you will figure out that no one of them will use a service like the one you are looking for. Every anti spam checks if the comments is submitted via Post, it looks to a private service to check if the message hit some antispam rules ( managed by the anti spam filter provider ) or similar. So I believe that the service you are looking for simply doesn't exist.
Also if it will be, there will be an interesting way to collect all valid email address in the world and the privacy ( the small privacy ) related to the knowledge of your email address will be completely destroyed.

At the end: can be an antispam filter a good way to filter messages, and then emails address, directly on your website before obtaining the email list?

Comment: I understand that. What I'm saying is that I wasn't paying attention to who was registering on the site, and after awhile there was like 15,000+ emails and users registered. Many of them were just stupid stuff like DSKFsdkfadf@dksdlfkds.com or something like that.

Comment: Sorry, I believed you collected them from comments, not from registration process. Probably you can at least ask for the ip of the domains at one DNS server.

Comment: Yeah, that was my next idea.. I'm thinking about creating a script to do that.